# Streaming data from node js controller to web page continuously

Tags: node.js, angular

I have a very large nodejs controller that runs thru huge tables and checks data against other huge tables. This takes quite a while to run.

Today my page only shows the final result after 20 minutes.

Is there anyway to stream out the result continuously from the controller to the web page?  Like a real time scrolling log of whats going on?

(or is Socket I.O. my only option)

Comment: websockets is your only option or if you want you can do polling with a setInterval that fires a new http request

Comment: Well I was about to suggest Socket.io before reading your last line, what makes you not want it in your scenario?

Comment: Socket.io is a good option, to start look at this tutorial https://www.valentinog.com/blog/socket-io-node-js-react/

Answer (score 0):

You can try with node-cron and set the dynamic query for fetching data with different limits and append data in the front-end side.

I am not sure is it a proper way or not.

Comment: Its a bit too risky with dynamic querys - but interesting idea :-)

Comment: Thank you and try it if you think it will work for you